# How to create a c++ class that can send and receive window message in MFC

Tags: c++, windows, mfc

I just want to create a C++ class which can send and process window messages in MFC.
I had tried many ways that I obtained from the internet, roughly like this:

1. create class myClass::public CWnd using the class Wizard from visual studio 2019 community version.
2. Use the following code in constructor

```
CString wcn = ::AfxRegisterWndClass(NULL);

BOOL created = this->CreateEx(0, wcn, _T("YourExcellentWindowClass"), 0, { 0, 0, 0, 0 }, this->GetParent(), /*HWND_MESSAGE,*/ 0, 0);
```

3. Setup Message map

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(myClass, CWnd)
    ON_MESSAGE(WM_USER + 1, DoNOOP)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()
```

4. write message process function:

```
afx_msg LRESULT myClass::DoNOOP(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    AfxMessageBox(_T("Get Reaaady for a Ruuummmmmmmbllllle!"));
    return LRESULT(true);
}
```

5. Sent in message from parent window:

```
    myClass* hmw = new myClass();
    ::SendMessage(hmw->m_hWnd, WM_USER + 1, 0, 0);
```

It passed Build process. However, when I run it in debugging mode, SendMessge triggered a Breakpoint in here:

```
_AFXWIN_INLINE CWnd* CWnd::GetParent() const
    { ASSERT(::IsWindow(m_hWnd)); return CWnd::FromHandle(::GetParent(m_hWnd)); }
```

which is in afxwin2.inl

I really don't know what to do now.
Please help. I will really appreciate it.

The complete class declaration:

```
#pragma once

class CMyMessageOnlyWindowClass : public CWnd
{
    DECLARE_DYNAMIC(CMyMessageOnlyWindowClass)

public:
    CMyMessageOnlyWindowClass();
    virtual ~CMyMessageOnlyWindowClass();

protected:
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
    afx_msg LRESULT DoNOOP(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
};
```

Implementation:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "MFCmsg.h"
#include "CMyMessageOnlyWindowClass.h"

// CMyMessageOnlyWindowClass

IMPLEMENT_DYNAMIC(CMyMessageOnlyWindowClass, CWnd)

CMyMessageOnlyWindowClass::CMyMessageOnlyWindowClass()
{
    CString wcn = ::AfxRegisterWndClass(NULL);
    BOOL created = this->CreateEx(0, wcn, _T("YourExcellentWindowClass"), 0, { 0, 0, 0, 0 }, this->GetParent(), /*HWND_MESSAGE,*/ 0, 0);
}

CMyMessageOnlyWindowClass::~CMyMessageOnlyWindowClass()
{
}

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CMyMessageOnlyWindowClass, CWnd)
    ON_MESSAGE(WM_USER + 1, DoNOOP)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

// CMyMessageOnlyWindowClass message handlers
afx_msg LRESULT CMyMessageOnlyWindowClass::DoNOOP(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    AfxMessageBox(_T("Get Reaaady for a Ruuummmmmmmbllllle!"));
    return LRESULT(true);
}
```

The main Window is a dialog with only OK and Cancel button.
When click on OK,

```
void CMFCmsgDlg::OnBnClickedOk()
{
    CMyMessageOnlyWindowClass* hmw = new CMyMessageOnlyWindowClass();
    hmw->SendMessage(WM_USER + 1);
    CDialogEx::OnOK();
}
```

and this will trigger a breakpoint. Please help.

Comment: If you don't know what what you're doing and can't work it out from following examples, then you should show a _complete and minimal example_.  Otherwise, how can you know that you haven't left out something important?

Comment: You don't need to create a class derived from `CWnd` to process your user custom messages. You can derive from `CCmdTarget`, and not even need to do its `CreateEx/Create`. This way you will not get parenting problems.

Comment: Can you provide a sample for me to learn from it? Appreciate it.